# SharePoint 2010 Kerberos Configuration Troubleshooter

Tags: 2010, 2013, kerberos

Can someone say if it's possible to download fresh version of "[SharePoint 2010 Kerberos Configuration Troubleshooter](https://support.microsoft.com/ru-ru/kb/2732019?wa=wsignin1.0)" utility?

The problem I've got a program **SDP.0b21cdb73234323739363835353551.Run.exe** from Microsoft support that's already 'expired'. I've run it once on one of the SharePoint farms. Now, I really want the same programramme for later use one other servers.

Just look at the reports it produces:
[image]

[image]
Isn't it great? It checks for dozes potential issues and shows the results in neat reports.

I really don't understand why this utility is not accessible for public use. I can only imagine the amout of pain it can save for many people who try to setup Kerberos.

Is there a way I can get this utility for SP2010 or SP2013 that never gets 'expired'?